# Regex - explode a string based on backslash character that has inconsistent occurrences

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I am using laravel php and trying to explode a string into an array. the string always has the slash character, but the character can occur many times:

Example:

- the input string: `"abcd\\efg\\\\hij\klm\\\\\\\opq"`
- the expected array: `[abcd, efg, hij, klm, opq]`

I have tried to use `str_replace` function to replace `'\'` to `''` , but but it gives wrong results, since i won't have any delimiter to use when exploding my string.

I know that regex can do this but i have no clue how to achieve that.

I hope someone can assist me on this matter.

Comment: [``preg_split('`/+`', $string)``](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6W4pCgzL13BVkEpMSk5RV8/NS1dHwgyMrP0s3Ny9cEgv6BQyZqrLLEoPqU0t0CjoCg1Pb64ICezREM9QV87QV1HAWqMpqb1//8A)

Comment: You can do like this [https://paiza.io/projects/FS-3ev7ZMySojD3GgAVtXw?language=php]( Onpline Editor )

Comment: Surprisingly, I can't find a duplicate for this question

Comment: @ctwheels my bad i have edited the question.. it's actually a backslash not a slash.. when i use ur suggestions i get an error stating that `preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`

Comment: @Alladin updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `preg_split` with the regex `/+` (match one or more `/` characters) to split on variable length substring of `/` characters:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6W4pCgzL13BVkEpMSk5RV8/NS1dHwgyMrP0s3Ny9cEgv6BQyZqrLLEoPqU0t0CjoCg1Pb64ICezREM9QV87QV1HAWqMpqb1//8A)

```
<?php

$string = "abcd//efg////hij/klm//////opq";
var_dump(preg_split('`/+`', $string));
```

---

**Update**

Updated since OP changed split character and string to backslash `\`.

Similar to the forward slash shown above, backslash can also be matched using the regex `\\\\+`. You need to escape the backslashes for the string and the regex, so `\\\\+` becomes string `\\+`, which becomes raw regex `\+`:

[See code in use here](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxr4go4CLS6W4pCgzL13BVkEpMSk5JSYmNS09BggyMrNisnNyYyAgv6BQyZqrLLEoPqU0t0CjoCg1Pb64ICezRENdHySvra@uowA1SlPT@v9/AA)

```
<?php

$string = "abcd\\efg\\\\hij\klm\\\\\\\opq";
var_dump(preg_split('/\\\\+/', $string));
```

Comment: I am sorry i made a mistake. i have edited the question.. it's actually a backslash not a slash.. when i use ur suggestions i get an error stating that `preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash`